# Scroll Bar Fade In Pushing Text Issue

Tags: html, css

### Issue

I have created the effect on my List element inside my application so that the scroll bar will appear when I hover over the List element. This is great and is working as expected.

The issue that is happening is when the scroll bar appears it seems to push the text inside the list to fit the scroll bar in, I am wondering is there a way I can set the scroll bars to overlay over the element?

Please see link below that shows a GIF representing the issue:

https://media.giphy.com/media/3oxHQrFD8iJiH39b5m/giphy.gif

### Code

```
ul
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

ul:hover {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben, will you be able to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Just use the built-in jsfiddle snippet and show us the html markup with its relevant css.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are using `%` width. It will resize as your "100%" get smaller with scrollbar.
You can set `ul` width static (the same of his parent). In that way, when the scrollbar appears, your content won't be pushed.

Comment: @M Jr I have tried setting a PX width and it still does not work. I took the width out altogether and this did work but i need it to be 100% width.

Comment: Then try to work with the scrollbar size and, after hover, update the `ul` width. Can you give some html example of what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

css is not able to read the scrollbar size, therefore setting padding as a placeholder is not possible. with js u could do this, by comparing width with and without scrollbar